Is there a way add Creators addresses to an NFT with Token Extensions like Metaplex does?
I followed this tutorial to create NFTs with Token Extensions: https://solana.com/developers/guides/token-extensions/dynamic-meta-data-nft, however I don't see a way to add the Creators and display them in the explorer. Is there a way to do that?
Thanks.

There isn't a field in the metadata extension interface explicitly to set creators.
Here is the metadata extension account struct and it contains the additional_metadata field which you can use to add additional metadata which is a vector of tuples.
pub struct TokenMetadata {
    /// The authority that can sign to update the metadata
    pub update_authority: OptionalNonZeroPubkey,
    /// The associated mint, used to counter spoofing to be sure that metadata
    /// belongs to a particular mint
    pub mint: Pubkey,
    /// The longer name of the token
    pub name: String,
    /// The shortened symbol for the token
    pub symbol: String,
    /// The URI pointing to richer metadata
    pub uri: String,
    /// Any additional metadata about the token as key-value pairs. The program
    /// must avoid storing the same key twice.
    pub additional_metadata: Vec<(String, String)>,
}

Example
const metaData: TokenMetadata = {
  updateAuthority: updateAuthority,
  mint: mint,
  name: "OPOS",
  symbol: "OPOS",
  uri: "https://raw.githubusercontent.com/solana-developers/opos-asset/main/assets/DeveloperPortal/metadata.json",
  additionalMetadata: [["creator1", "Cooldev"]],
};

However, I'd use this sparingly as you pay for what you use on Solana in terms of storage space
reference https://solana.com/developers/guides/token-extensions/metadata-pointer

Thanks for your reply. I tried like this and metadata is added, but it is not displayed in the explorer in the Token Creators section.
https://solana.fm/address/GtEXAgvgkG8kjm9anw9wxQ1cyMudmziXesenSGnbvctx/transactions

This is specific to the explorer. Check under the Metadata tab for SolanaFM. You can view it here on the Solana explorer https://explorer.solana.com/address/GtEXAgvgkG8kjm9anw9wxQ1cyMudmziXesenSGnbvctx?cluster=devnet
